# compress image size before saving in database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, image-processing, image-compression

Is there any way to compress or reduce image size during uploading at client side and before saving in database in javascript?

There are some options i have seen but they are using PHP i want that in javascript with HTML. I am using Django framework so it will be easier to implement in JS rather than in PHP.

When we are uploading that image it should be compressed automatically and then it will be saved in database.

Comment: Search for "client side image resize". It's possible to do using javascript and the `canvas` web api.

Comment: Please show some attempt at this. There is a lot of information to gain from a quick Google search.